# Run jquery scripts on client side with a HttpHandler (by Implement IHttpHandler)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a User Control that need load some jquery scripts  in client side, at this time I handle it like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQueryScriptHeader", 
Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "MyNamespace.js.jquery-
1.6.4.min.js"));


Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("MyScript", 
Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "MyNamespace.js.MyScript.js"));
        }
```

Also I have a new script that has jQuery.Post() and I think for fire it need a HttpHaandler

How can I do All this with HttpHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful this very like as your problem an have a complete step by step solution:

[use return value of json in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993160/use-return-value-of-json-in-jquery-ajax-script-correctly)